# Algebraic extension which is not finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

It's well known that given a field $K$, an extension $F/K$ is finite if and only if $F$ is algebraic and finitely generated. Naturally, this suggests the existence of algebraic extensions which are not finitely generated. In trying to think of such examples, the only one that I came up with would be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Are there examples of non-finitely generated algebraic extensions which can be described without saying it's the algebraic closure of something? Mainly because the existence of the closure doesn't give me a good intuition as to exactly what the extension field is composed of.

Comment: $\bar{\Bbb Q}$-the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: Why not $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}, \ldots)$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor a good example, but it should probably be noted that it's not so simple to prove that that extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite, even if it's intuitively plausible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what description you want to see. For example, $F=\mathbb{Q}(\{\sqrt[n]{2}: n\in\mathbb{N}\})$ is clearly an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is not finite, and so not finitely generated.

A short explanation to why the extension is infinite: for each $n$ the polynomial $x^n-2\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion, and so $\sqrt[n]{2}$ is an algebraic number of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. So we have:

$[F:\mathbb{Q}]\geq [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=n \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

And so the extension degree is infinite.

Comment: Indeed, though, still, with quibbling, in ultra-elementary terms for example, why is there no fourth root of $2$ in the field generated by the square root? :) Maybe adding a little would be more helpful to a beginner. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Because $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is algebraic of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. In general, $x^n-2$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (by Eisenstein's criterion), and so $\sqrt[n]{2}$ has degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. It follows that the degree of the field extension I defined is larger than any natural number, and so it has to be infinite.

Comment: indeed, and this would be a good addition to your answer, in my opinion. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Alright, I added a few details.

Comment: Appreciate the very clear answer and explanation!